# Get all applications from azure active directory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I am fetching application from active directory. Total number of applications are increased and now they are above 999. Maximum number of items in one page can be 999. I want to fetch all applications in one page collection.
I am using following code to fetch applications, but it seems that there is no method in activedirectory client to return all apps in one call.

Can I make collection of pages and append all pages using do while?

```
IPagedCollection<IApplication> applications = null;

 applications = await activeDirectoryClient.Applications.Take(999).ExecuteAsync()
```

Comment: try using rest api directly. Maybe the SDK version you're using does not support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get all the applications like this:

```
        List<IApplication> applicationList = new List<IApplication>();
        IPagedCollection<IApplication> pagedCollection = activeDirectoryClient.Applications.ExecuteAsync().Result;
        do
        {
            applicationList.AddRange(pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList());

            pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;

        } while (pagedCollection != null && pagedCollection.MorePagesAvailable);
```

Comment: Thanks. it works but null initialization of applicationlist is not working and require changes.